Using upstream Parameter to determine if downstream data aware DAG should run
I would like to have the DAG scheduled to run if both the dataset table is updated and the upstream DAG has a param called kick_off_downstream_dag set to true:
# DAG definition
@dag(
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(year=2023, month=1, day=1, tz="America/New_York"),
    schedule=dataset if "{{ (triggering_dataset_events.values() | first | first).source_dag_run.conf['kick_off_downstream_dag']}}" else None,
    description=None,
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args=DAG_ARGS,
)

